# Woocommerce checkout fields - how to pass data attribute in select option

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On Woocomemrce checkout i have 2 default select fields: billing_state and billing_city

When i select a billing_state i need the billing_city to be populated only with its children. I use select2 plugin to select the items.

For example, when i select Italy, i want at the billing_city to appear only Rome and Milan.

```
<select name="billing_state" id="billing_state">
  <option value="1">USA</option>
  <option value="2">Italy</option>
</select>

<select name="billing_city" id="billing_city">
  <option value="1" data-parent="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2" data-parent="1">Washington</option>
  <option value="3" data-parent="2">Rome</option>
  <option value="4" data-parent="2">Milan</option>
</select>
```

For the select field i pass a php $array_cities with id=>name from custom table, but i don't know how to pass a data-parent="" attribute to select only those children with jQuery.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = array(
        'label'         => 'Cities',
        'placeholder'   => false,
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-first'),
        'clear'         => false , 
        'type'          => 'select',
        'options'       => $array_cities
     );

    return $fields;
}
```

If cannot be done via default Woocommerce fields, i think to to a custom billing_city_custom select to deal with this selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install below woo commerce plugin:

[WC City Select](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-city-select/)

Place below code into your function.php file.

```
add_filter( 'wc_city_select_cities', 'my_cities' );

/*** Replace XX with the country code. Instead of YYY, ZZZ use actual  state codes.*/


function my_cities( $cities ) {
    $cities['XX'] = array(
        'YYY' => array(
            'City ',
            'Another City'
        ),
        'ZZZ' => array(
            'City 3',
            'City 4'
        )
    );
    return $cities;
}

Below is an example of it:

add_filter( 'wc_city_select_cities', 'my_cities' ); 

function my_cities( $cities ) {
    $cities['US'] = array(
        'AL' => array(
            'City1 of Alabama1',
            'City2 of Alabama1'
        ),
        'NJ' => array(
            'City1 of New Jersey',
            'City2 of New Jersey'
        ),
        'OK' => array(
            'City1 of Oklahoma',
            'City2 of Oklahoma',
            'City3 of Oklahoma',
            'City4 of Oklahoma'
        )
    );
    return $cities;
}
```

Comment: I have managed to work with this plugin. Initially it didn't worked because i disabled country and zip code fields (do not unset them or delete them when reorder fields). Let all default fields enabled, but hide them via css if you need.

Another similar plugin i have found is 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/states-cities-and-places-for-woocommerce/